# Android - Create animation 'Drag Up To Lock'

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, transition

Does anyone have even a remote idea of how to create an animation like the one shown in the [**Pocket App**](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.citc.wallet&feature=search_result) where the user can drag a small bar (like the notification bar) from the bottom of the screen all the way up, making the app lock itself and change the current activity?

I'm just wondering how to do the animation, if it is a built in thing in android, or something more complexe. Can anyone give me some guidance of how to search/build a similar animation, please?

For those who are not familiar with the animation and do not know the app /did not understand my description, you can see it [**here**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iADbFYQo-Jc)

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could tryout the sliding drawer.

Or for this sort of animation you will need a layout which you place in the bottom and add a onThumbTouchListener.

Something like this

```
OnTouchListener onThumbTouch = new OnTouchListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
        {   
            switch(v.getId())
            {
                case R.id.slider_thumb_id:
                {
                    switch(event.getAction())
                    {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        {                           
                            if(v.getTop()>=0 && v.getBottom()<sliderFrame.getMeasuredHeight()){
                                int topPos = (int)event.getRawY()-(v.getHeight()*2+v.getHeight());
                                if(topPos < 0) {
                                    topPos=0;
                                } else if(topPos > (sliderFrame.getMeasuredHeight()-v.getMeasuredHeight())){
                                    topPos = (sliderFrame.getMeasuredHeight()-v.getMeasuredHeight()) -1;
                                }   
                                iconParams.topMargin = topPos;
                                v.setLayoutParams(iconParams);
                                sliderThumbFake.setLayoutParams(iconParams);
                            }                           
                            break;
                        }
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        {                           

                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
```

The code inside the case statements might not be useful as it was something I sued for my requirement. But this how you do a drag of a view.

Comment: Sliding drawer is the way to go. Thank you